# Combine Lists to dictionary keeping first value of repetitive key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to combine two lists that have repetitive keys and keep the first value instead of the last.
When doing:

```
keys = ['HT202039',
 'HT202039',
 'HT202039',
 'HT202039',
 'HT202039',
 'HT202039',
 'HT202039',
 'HT206627',
 'HT212048',
 'HT203905']
    
values = [0.9527516324191851,
 0.9415256727935831,
 0.9393113073236541,
 0.9258447486583915,
 0.8796238049268982,
 0.8760262341331504,
 0.8722470299246854,
 0.48326164037445074,
 0.4720068674708344,
 0.46248035502320567]

 dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

it returns: `{'HT202039': 0.8722470299246854, 'HT206627': 0.48326164037445074, 'HT212048': 0.4720068674708344, 'HT203905': 0.46248035502320567}`

but I would instead like to keep the first value for the key, so it would look like this instead:

```
{'HT202039': 0.9527516324191851, 'HT206627': 0.48326164037445074, 'HT212048': 0.4720068674708344, 'HT203905': 0.46248035502320567}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove the dict() closure, you will see the duplicates are not removed. I would adjust the logic to suit what you want, rather than wrapping it as dict() and then trying to change behavior

Answer (score 3):

Try to iterate backwards:

```py
dictionary = dict(zip(reversed(keys), reversed(values)))
print(dictionary)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "HT203905": 0.46248035502320567,
    "HT212048": 0.4720068674708344,
    "HT206627": 0.48326164037445074,
    "HT202039": 0.9527516324191851,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary  = {}
for k,v in zip(keys, values):
    if k not in dictionary :
        dictionary [k] = v
```

Output:

```
{'HT202039': 0.9527516324191851,
 'HT206627': 0.48326164037445074,
 'HT212048': 0.4720068674708344,
 'HT203905': 0.46248035502320567}
```